# Create custom lists for several polygons in ArcGIS Field Maps

Tags: arcgis

I am hoping to start using the ArcGIS Field Maps app for field work. I have a shapefile with several polygons that represent different field sites. I would like to create a custom list of species for each of these different polygons (i.e., species that have been identified at this location before) so that in future years I can check whether species that have previously been observed at this site are still present. Is there an easy way to do that or do the field have to be exactly the same for every polygon in a shapefile?

Thank you for your help!

I have tried to figure it out by playing with Field Maps but I can't seem to figure it out!